# How can a function returning the address of the variable return zero?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int *addressof();

int main()

{               
    int *p=addressof();
    printf("%u",p);
    return 0; 
}            
int *addressof()
{
    int x=9;
    
    return &x;
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Can the address of the variable be zero? Is it possible?

Comment: Node that the `%u` format specifier for `printf` expects an `unsigned int` argument. To print a `void *` pointer (you need to cast to be correct) use `%p`. Mismatching format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your pointer will always point to released memory block and will never be valid.

Answer (score 5):

The code you have written have undefined behavior as it returns the address of a local variable which will have been released when the function returns. In this case the compiler is can choose to optimize it and return 0.

If you change the variable to a static instead the address you return will be valid

```
int *addressof()
{
    static int x=9;
    
    return &x;
}
```

Check the warnings from your compiler, the second problem is, the size of a pointer is not necessarily the same as `unsigned long`, replace `"%u"` with `"%p"` in the `printf`.

Answer (score 3):

*Note: This is an addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759001/391691), which covers some reason why you got zero.*

Depending on your target system and its compiler, **of course** a variable can have an address of zero. This is the case for example on MCS51 microcontrollers, where (external) RAM starts at 0 and is used for variables. Unfortunately in that system `NULL` is also defined as a zero pointer, which makes common usages *difficult*.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%p",&p);
```

You will get the output.

Comment: You're printing the address of `p`, not the address that was returned from the function call.